# VBA - Error 1004 - XLOOKUP on another Workbook ends in error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm Writing a function to use the XLOOKUP formula to get 1 numerical Value from another Workbook and return it as double/comma number.
Here's the code:

```
Function searchColumnVLP(ByRef b As Worksheet, ByRef v As Variant) As Double
Dim Val As Variant

Val = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(v, b.Range("A:A"), b.Range("T:T"))

searchColumnVLP = Val

End Function
```

A Demo could be:

```
Public Sub CreateTable_Click()
'Open an invisible excel app to store the correct WB
Set appExcel = New Application
appExcel.Visible = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim t as Range

'Worksheets will remain invisible, no new window appears in the screen '
Set wb = GetObject("*PATH of a xlsx file different from the currently open one with multiple sheets*")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("*The sheet with the data*")
Set t = ws.Range("B2")

t.Value = searchColumnVLP(ws, "123")
wsData.Close

wsSource.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

My problem is the error '1004' "Unable to get the XLOOKUP property of the WorksheetFunction class", I don't know how to resolve this.

Val could probably be "without value" or "unassigned" but this are just my guessing based on what I know about VBA (not that much :D).

Any kind of help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

XLOOKUP is not currently a supported WorksheetFunction Method.

One way to get around this without writing too much VBA code would be to instead have the VBA code place the XLOOKUP function into the cell that you are wanting the value in.

For example:

```
Set t = ws.Range("B2")

t.Formula2 = "=XLOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_array,return_array)"
```

Be aware that the lookup value lookup array, and return array in this example will need to be formatted as text so you will need a few lines of code to do that, but it is 100% doable.

Comment: What is the difference between `Formula` and `Formula2`?